# KineticJS - How can we move an image behind a mask without moving mask

Tags: image, kineticjs, mask

Is it possible to move an image behind a mask without moving the mask itself ? I am looking for an operation which allow to move an image behind a mask and it should be accurate and smooth.

The best answer I am looking is to mask an Kinetic.Image object. Kinetic.Image is draggable and need to worry about it's movement. Please let me know if it's really possible to mask Kinetic.Image Object ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "mask".  A clipping mask? An opacity mask?  A mask created by compositing?

Comment: yes. I got it working fine for Clipping Mask. This is how I handled this situation: 1. Made a non draggable Group and set it's clipping boundary. 2. Added an Kinetic.Image Object which is draggable. This work like charm without any performance hit. This approach solved my problem to some extent. But still can't get it working for arbitrary shape.

Comment: I need to get it working for any shape and not only rectangle or square. Ex: Make a shape using Kinetic.RegularPolygon. Now how can we make it clip an Kinetic.Image Object so that the shape is non-draggable, but we can drag the Image within this clipped area ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/u28MS/

Use a Kinetic.Shape to get access to the canvas context and then create a clipping region.

- Create a new Kinetic.Shape
- Define your non-rectangular path in the shape
- Call clip() to restrict drawing to that path.
- Draw the image into the clipping region.
- Give the image x & y properties so that the image can be draw

Here's what that looks like in code:

```
// create a Kinetic.Shape which gives you access
// to a context to draw on

clippingShape = new Kinetic.Shape({
    sceneFunc: function(context) {

      // define your path here
      // context.beginPath(); ...

      // make your path a clipping region

      context.clip();

      // draw the image inside the clipping region
      // img.x & img.y are offsets which can be used
      // to "drag" the image around the clipping region

      context.drawImage(img,img.x,img.y);

      // KineticJS specific context method
      context.fillStrokeShape(this);

    },
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    listening:false
});
```

Listen for mouse events on the stage to cause the image to reposition when drawn in the Shape.

- In mousedown: Save the mouse position and set a flag indicating the drag has begun.
- In mousemove: Calc how much the mouse has moved and offset the image's x/y by that distance.
- In mouseup: clear the dragging flag since the drag is over.

The mouse event handlers look like this:

```
var isdown=false;

stage.getContent().onmousedown=function(e){ 
    var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
    img.lastX=parseInt(pos.x);
    img.lastY=parseInt(pos.y);
    isdown=true; 
};
stage.getContent().onmouseup=function(e){ 
    isdown=false; 
};
stage.getContent().onmousemove=function(e){
    if(!isdown){return;}
    var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
    var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
    var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
    var dx=mouseX-img.lastX;
    var dy=mouseY-img.lastY;
    img.lastX=mouseX;
    img.lastY=mouseY;
    img.x+=dx;
    img.y+=dy;
    layer.draw();
};
```

**[ Previous version of answer -- replaced with new answer above after questioners commments ]**

This kind of clipping is traditionally done with a foreground image that contains a transparent "viewport" which lets the user see a portion of the background image beneath.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2f9yu/

[image]

Create a draggable background image on a bottom layer:

```
// create a background layer

var bottomLayer=new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(bottomLayer);

// put a draggable image on the background layer

var city=new Kinetic.Image({ image:bk,x:0,y:0,draggable:true,width:700,height:440, });
bottomLayer.add(city);
bottomLayer.draw();
```

Create a non-draggable foreground image on a top layer.

The top image has a transparent "viewport".

Important: the top layer does not listen for events, so dragging moves the bottom image, not the top image.

```
// create a top layer that does not respond to mouse events
// any mouse events will filter down to the background image
// this enables the background to be dragged even while behind the top image

var topLayer=new Kinetic.Layer({listening:false,});
stage.add(topLayer);

// create a top image with transparent pixels 
// used as a viewport to see a portion of the bottom image

var mirror=new Kinetic.Image({ image:viewport,x:0,y:0 });
topLayer.add(mirror);
topLayer.draw();
```

Example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:300px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 300
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var bottomLayer=new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(bottomLayer);
    var topLayer=new Kinetic.Layer({listening:false,});
    stage.add(topLayer);

    var loadedCount=0;
    //
    var bk=new Image();
    bk.onload=start;
    bk.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/desert1.jpg";
    //
    var viewport=new Image();
    viewport.onload=start;
    viewport.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/car4.png";

    function start(){
        if(++loadedCount<2){return;}

        var city=new Kinetic.Image({ image:bk,x:0,y:0,draggable:true,width:700,height:440, });
        bottomLayer.add(city);
        bottomLayer.draw();

        var mirror=new Kinetic.Image({ image:viewport,x:0,y:0 });
        topLayer.add(mirror);
        topLayer.draw();

    }


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Drag to move the background image in the mirror</h4>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast. It's acceptable solution where we have multiple layers and top layer do not listen to mouse activities. This enable the bottom layer to listen and act accordingly. This solution is also perfect to have any arbitrary shape in the form of transparent pixels to have a see through for background layer.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your response. It still do not solve the issue where we want to have a shape surrounded by transparent pixels and allow us to drag the underlying Image bounded by the shape where Image is not visible outside shape area. Please let me know in case it's possible ? It will help me a lot to crack a situation I am facing.

Comment: I see...transparent pixels on the mask where you don't want the underlying clipped image to appear. OK, after checking, I see that the recent KineticJS versions of the Kinetic.Shape support context.clip (Yea!).  So it should be possible to (1) use a Kinetic.Shape as a clipping mask for an image. (2) listen for mouse events on the stage and create a "drag" that repositions the clipped-image inside the Shape.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the updated solution. This seems good one where we can use a Shape to clip an Image.